# Get user data pass to table view?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch, view

I want developed a similar alarm application to remind user send message, and my question is I want get user field in data like numbers, message and date to table view by array.

I do this use tabbar controller,my first view is gave to user field in all data and check save button. My second view is table view to remind user.

Now I can save the data in NSMutableArray by one time only, where I save the data again, the old data with replace. Anyone know how to do this?

My code here.

Here is save button for another view.

I call FirstView

```
- (IBAction)SaveAll:(id)sender{

    if(numText.text == nil || textView.text == nil || Selectime == nil){
        NSLog(@"error becos value null");

        UIAlertView *errorview = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error Info" message:@"You nomber , message text or date no input or select.Pls fill in all. "delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [errorview show];
        [errorview release];
    }else{
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;
    DataClass *obj=[DataClass getInstance]; 
    localNotif.fireDate = obj.showdate;

        NSString *getdate = [obj.showdate description];
        [defaults setObject:getdate forKey:@"date"];
    NSLog(@"localNotif = %@", localNotif.fireDate);
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];

        obj.showdate = nil;


    NSString *getnum =numText.text;
    [defaults setObject:getnum forKey:@"keyToLookupString"];

    // Notification details
   // localNotif.alertBody = [eventText text];
        NSString *getmessage = self.textView.text;
        [defaults setObject:getmessage forKey:@"message"];

    localNotif.alertBody = self.textView.text;
    NSLog(@"alertBody message = %@",localNotif.alertBody);

    // Set the action button
    localNotif.alertAction = @"Send Now?";

    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;


    // Specify custom data for the notification
    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"someValue" forKey:@"someKey"];
    localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

    // Schedule the notification
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
            [localNotif release];



    numText.text = @"";
    textView.text = @"";
    Selectime.text = @"";
    self.textView.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"Event Here....",);

        SaveDataView *savedata = [[SaveDataView alloc]initWithNibName:@"SaveView" bundle:nil];
        [savedata.tableview reloadData];
    }

}
```

In my table view controller I call SaveDataView.

SaveDataView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface SaveDataView : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>{
IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;
    NSMutableArray *MessageArray;
    NSMutableArray *NomberArray;
    NSMutableArray *DateArray;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *MessageArray;
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *NomberArray;
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *DateArray;

@end
```

SaveDataView.m

```
#import "SaveDataView.h"
#import "DataClass.h"
#import "SMSAppDelegate.h"
@implementation SaveDataView
@synthesize tableview;
@synthesize MessageArray,NomberArray,DateArray;

- (void) viewWillAppear {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *messageShow =[defaults stringForKey:@"message"];
    NSString *nomberShow = [defaults stringForKey:@"keyToLookupString"];
    NSString *dateShow = [defaults stringForKey:@"date"];

    [MessageArray addObject:messageShow];
    NSLog(@"MessageArray = %@",MessageArray);
    [NomberArray addObject:nomberShow];
    NSLog(@"NomberArray = %@",NomberArray);
    [DateArray addObject:dateShow];
    NSLog(@"DateArray = %@",DateArray);

    [self.tableview reloadData];
    NSLog(@"checking.... ");
    //[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
// The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
/*
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization.
    }
    return self;
}
*/


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"table view viewDidLoad");


    MessageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NomberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    DateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //  [MessageArray insertObject:messageShow atIndex:[MessageArray count]];
    [self viewWillAppear];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}


/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    //return [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count];
    NSLog(@"in nsinteger tableview");
    return [self.MessageArray count];
    return [self.NomberArray count];
    return [self.DateArray count];

}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"in uitableviewcell...");
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    // if (cell == nil) {
    //  cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    //} 
    // Configure the cell...

    //NSArray *notificationArray = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
    //UILocalNotification *notif = [notificationArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //  NSString *enNote = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:string];

    NSString *showmessage = [MessageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *shownomber = [NomberArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *showdate = [DateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell.textLabel setText:showmessage];
    NSLog(@"table view settext = %@",showmessage);
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];



    NSString *abc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n %@", shownomber,showdate];
//NSString *abc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n %@", nomber,[notif.fireDate description]];
    [cell.detailTextLabel  setText:abc];
    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    NSLog(@"table view detailTextLabel = %@,%@",shownomber,showdate);
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    return cell;

    [self.tableview reloadData];
}




@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the viewDidLoad with viewWillappear...viewDidLoad is called only once when you loaded the view so you cant able to replace the array. viewWillappear is called everytime when the view is appeared on the screen...

EDIT:afer seeing the comments.
keep the viewdidload as it is . add these codes to your application.

```
  -(void)viewwillappear
    {
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *messageShow =[defaults stringForKey:@"message"];
    NSString *nomberShow = [defaults stringForKey:@"keyToLookupString"];
    NSString *dateShow = [defaults stringForKey:@"date"];

     [MessageArray addObject:messageShow];
    NSLog(@"MessageArray = %@",MessageArray);
    [NomberArray addObject:nomberShow];
    NSLog(@"NomberArray = %@",NomberArray);
    [DateArray addObject:dateShow];
     NSLog(@"DateArray = %@",DateArray);

    }
```

Comment: hi,i replace to viewWillappear but no work.- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {} use this???

Comment: hi,i change my code ady,but still no work..:( data still will replace oh?

Comment: ya,can my 3 array oso have data inside,but will i add new data again still will replace old one.izit use for loop to array???

Comment: just reload the tableview...  [theTable reloadData];

Comment: if you are getting the correct answers while using the NSLog means it will work... can  you post your tableview code...

Comment: see whether your tableview is calling or not after the [tableview reloaddata];

Comment: you want to add these lines in viewwill appear tableview.delegate = self;
tableview.dataSource = self; before reload data

Comment: still can not,but thanks to you.i will try find another problem.

Comment: sorry friend... now i dont have the mac... so i cant able to figure out your problem...

Comment: @Iphone @Aravindhanarvi Please don't use the commenting system on Stack Overflow as a personal discussion board. I'm deleting this conversation, take it to the chat system, IM, or facebook.